# MassTransit: publishing a event created an additional topic named fully namespace interface

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit

I have the following events

```
    public class MyEvent:BaseEvent
   {
   }

   public interface BaseEvent
   {
   }
```

when I publish using masstransit like the following

```
var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(
            cfg =>
            {
                cfg.Host(
                    new Uri(serviceBusUri),
                    h =>
                    {
                        h.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                        h.TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider(sharedAccessKeyName, sharedAccessKey, tokenTimeToLive, TokenScope.Namespace);
                    });
                cfg.UseRetry(r => r.None());
            });
var message= new MyEvent();
await this._busControl.Publish(message, typeof(MyEvent));
```

It created one extra topic named BaseEvent. Is it expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MassTransit will create topics to match the class/interface hierarchy to support polymorphic message routing to queues. Messages published that are derived types will automatically forward messages to higher level type topics. Receive endpoint queues are then bound to the appropriate topics through subscriptions that will forward messages to the queue.

It's similar to how [RabbitMQ](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/topology/rabbitmq.html#default-topology) works, with the difference being that Azure uses subscriptions to forward to other topics/queues.

Comment: Thank you very much  @chris for your prompt and informative reply